# Pinterest URL Debugger Grabbing Old Info

Tags: pinterest, facebook-opengraph

Running a URL through the [Pinterest URL Debugger](https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/url-debugger), and it appears to be caching have old data. Is there a way to force a refresh similar to Facebook's debugger?

Answer (score 0):

I would attempt to clear your browser cache (I'm assuming it's ran in browser). 
Maybe it's also using an old cookie, so log out, clear your browser cache/history, then close and open it again. You could also try a different browser to access it.

You could also try changing some old data to see if there is a pinterest db process that's using old data, and an update might refresh it.

Otherwise, you may want to reach out to pinterest support.

Answer (score 0):

OK so it turns out that it was NOT holding on to old information, but rather I was using the incorrect tags for price and currency.

should be og:price:amount and og:price:currency

full documentation for the product type of rich pins: https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/rich-pins/products/

from above, minimum requirements:

`<meta property="og:title" content="Name of your product" />
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:price:amount" content="1.00" />
<meta property="og:price:currency" content="USD" />`